# Allocate a custom url for generated json data through wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a custom JSON API plugin (JSONAPI plugin is not working according to my requirements). I will generate JSON from queries but my question is how to access that JSON from url.

In other words.
* I am generating JSON by writing a wordpress plugin. 
* I want to specify a URL for that generated JSON.

Ex: 
Json : [jsondata] (generating from custom wordpress plugin).
when "www.yourwordpressblog.com/api/get_posts" is called my jsondata should come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by hooking a function callback to the `wp_ajax_*` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` actions. When a request is made to the `ajaxurl` with the `action` parameter, the hooks will be called with the action appended. The rest of the data is accessible using `$_POST` and you are free to `echo` whatever you want back to the browser, including JSON. Make sure to set the `Content-Type` header if you aren't sending back HTML.

For a guide on how to do this please see [Creating AJAX Functions in WordPress](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/creating-ajax-functions-in-wordpress/).